# useTranslation in NextJS project doesn't translate

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

The project I'm working on is already implementing useTranslation and it's working fine in all components/pages except for the one I'm currently working on. I've created a custom 404 error page and want to display the error message in 4 different languages. This is the related code:

404.tsx

```
import React from 'react';



import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import styled, { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';


type Props = {};


const StyledWrapper = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const StyledErrorCode = styled.p`
  font-family: ${({theme}) => theme.typography.fontFamily.default};
  font-size: 96px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #b56f3b;
`;

const StyledErrorMessage = styled.p`
  font-family: ${({theme}) => theme.typography.fontFamily.default};
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #b56f3b;
`;
const StyledUserMessage = styled.p`
  font-family: ${({theme}) => theme.typography.fontFamily.default};
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #b56f3b;
  margin-top: 2rem;
`;

const StyledIcon = styled.img`
  position: absolute;
  left: 3rem;
  top: 2rem;
`;
const StyledSafEcho = styled.p`
  position: absolute;
  color: #b56f3b;
  left: 5.5rem;
  top: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
`;

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    background: #1d2538;
    margin: 0; /* Remove default body margin */
  }
`;

const Custom404 = (props: Props) => {
  const {t} = useTranslation('common');
  const errorMessage = t('page-not-found')
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <StyledWrapper>
        <StyledIcon src="/images/safecho-icon-error-page.svg"></StyledIcon>
        <StyledSafEcho>SafEcho</StyledSafEcho>
        <StyledErrorCode>404</StyledErrorCode>
        <StyledErrorMessage>{errorMessage}</StyledErrorMessage>
        <StyledUserMessage>
          Sorry for the inconvenience, this page is currently unavailable.
        </StyledUserMessage>
      </StyledWrapper>
    </>
  );
};

export default Custom404;
```

_error.tsx

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';



import NextErrorComponent from 'next/error';
import type { ErrorProps } from 'next/error';



import { flush } from '@sentry/nextjs';
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';



import captureError from '@sfe/sentry/captureError';


interface AppErrorProps extends ErrorProps {
  err?: Error;
  hasGetInitialPropsRun?: boolean;
}

const AppError: NextPage<AppErrorProps> = ({
  hasGetInitialPropsRun,
  err,
  statusCode,
}) => {
  if (!hasGetInitialPropsRun && err) {
    captureError(err);
  }

  return <NextErrorComponent statusCode={statusCode} />;
};



AppError.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const errorInitialProps: AppErrorProps =
    await NextErrorComponent.getInitialProps(ctx);
  errorInitialProps.hasGetInitialPropsRun = true;
  if (ctx.err) {
    captureError(ctx.err);
    await flush(2000);
    return errorInitialProps;
  }
  captureError(
    new Error(`_error.tsx getInitialProps missing data at path: ${ctx.asPath}`),
  );
  await flush(2000);

  return errorInitialProps;
};

export default AppError;
```

I have implemented it the same exact way it's implemented in other places throughout the project, yet it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `useTranslation` function from `next-i18next`, not from `react-i18next`.

```
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
```

https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next#usetranslation
[image]

Comment: didn't work unfortunately